# Flutter textAlign: justify is not working in Japanese

Tags: flutter, dart

The　`textAlign: justify` in Flutter only seems to work for languages separated by spaces, such as English.

Is there a way to adjust the character spacing for each individual line in Japanese?

Real:

https://fromkato.com/webdev/css/properties/text-align#justify

Expected:

https://fromkato.com/webdev/css/properties/text-align#last-justify

sample code

```
Text(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a imperdiet ligula, at blandit nulla. Phasellus mattis elit non massa bibendum rhoncus. Morbi dapibus ante quis auctor blandit. Praesent ac pulvinar velit, consequat fringilla turpis. Nullam tincidunt sem ac dui maximus, nec luctus lectus lacinia. Morbi non nisl et mauris egestas accumsan. Praesent congue ex mollis, venenatis magna id, faucibus tellus. Donec suscipit porta enim at suscipit. Maecenas non interdum lectus, in pulvinar nisl. Nulla vel rhoncus neque, sit amet faucibus mi. Praesent varius nulla eros.',
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
)

Text(
  'よそは時間そんなにどんな発展家というのの時を移れですです。断然今度に反対界はもしその話ですただけへするて行くでをは独立知れませませて、それだけには合っますたありた。文学へ思うないのはとうてい一番でよほどらしくませまし。ようやくネルソンさんに干渉三つまだ満足にできるまし態度同じ主意どこか発展にというご関係たなうですて、このほかは私か言い方見込みがするから、三宅さんの訳を権力のそれにちょうどお注文となって私教師にお腐敗がしようにもう実お尋ねを読みなけれませて、どうもとうとう発展をなりたていたのをしませた。すなわちもっともお画にするのはたった不愉快と知らたば、その落がは込み入っなとに対して個人に入っていでたい。同じため盲目の日その個人も私中を減っごとくかと久原さんに仕上るありです、学校の時分たとい',
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
)
```

Comment: can you please post some code example that you have tried ?

Comment: I added code example. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self-resolved.

`letterSpacing` is logical pixel space.
So, You have to adjust to fit the `fontSize`.

```
Text(
  'サンプルテキスト'.split('').join(' '),
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
  style: const TextStyle(
    letterSpacing: -1,
  ),
),
```